# rails collection_check_boxes label not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following form to generate a collection of (nested) join table values, where

```
class Photo
    has_many   :keywordphotos
    has_many   :keywords, through: :keywordphotos
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :keywords
```

and the database has:

```
  create_table "keywords", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
```

form view:

```
<%= form_for(@photo) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:keywords, @keywords, :id, :name) do |keyword| %>
    <%= keyword.label { keyword.check_box } %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

is generating the following HTML

```
 <label for="photo_keywords_3"><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="photo[keywords][]" id="photo_keywords_3" /></label> 
 <label for="photo_keywords_5"><input type="checkbox" value="5" name="photo[keywords][]" id="photo_keywords_5" /></label> 
 <label for="photo_keywords_4"><input type="checkbox" value="4" name="photo[keywords][]" id="photo_keywords_4" /></label>
```

so the input values are correct (according to the database data), but I was expecting the `:name` object to populate the label. Why is my understanding mistaken and how can I get the name to appear after the check_box?
[note: `{ keyword.check_box + keyword.name }` was attempted, but returned `undefined method 'name' for #<ActionView::Helpers[...]` ]

Comment: Try `keyword.object.name`. The param key should also be `:keyword_ids` which maps to the `keyword_ids=` setter that takes an array of ids. Using `keywords=` will give you an assocation type missmatch error as it expects an array of records.

Comment: "but I was expecting the :name object to populate the label." - not when you provide a block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is done with that 4th argument as it seems to be ignored, but this is what I did to get it to work:

```
<%= form_for(@photo) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:keywords, @keywords, :id, :name) do |keyword| %>
    <%= keyword.label('check-box') do %> 
      <%= keyword.check_box %>
      <%= keyword.object.name %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```